# Sql Server 2014 Not recognizing 64 bit drivers for Office

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a SQL Server 2014 virtual machine.  It is a 64 bit version of SQL Server or a 64 bit Windows Server.  The SQL Server software was installed before I was hired by the Sysadmin.  He choose to have the 32 bit drivers for Access (Office) installed.  We’ve talked about it, he claims he did it because we are using a 32 bit version of Office 2010.
Anyway, I uninstalled the AccessRuntime_x32 and installed AccessRuntime_x64. I’ve downloaded both the 2010 and 2013 versions off the Microsoft Website.  I’ve restarted SQL Server, I’ve even rebooted the whole server.  Yet I still can’t export out more than 64,000 rows of data for Excel nor can I choose a new version of Microsoft Excel past 2007.  What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to indicate how it is that you're trying to export data out to Excel. Are you using SSIS? DTS? BCP? OPENQUERY? Linked server?

Comment: This sounds like an installation/OS issue... you might have better luck posting this question on [SuperUser] (http://superuser.com/) or the [DBA StackExchange] (http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Tom H, I've tried SSIS, SSRS and The import export wizard within SQL Server Management studio.  I get the same error that says Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Thank you DanK.  I headed over to DBA StackExchange and asked my question.  I was able to get the answer I needed.  For anyone else who has this issue, here is the solution I was given that worked for me:                                               http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133588/sql-server-2014-not-recognizing-64-bit-drivers-for-office

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting this on dba StackExchange and was given the answer:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133588/sql-server-2014-not-recognizing-64-bit-drivers-for-office

One of the users there posted this:  I downloaded the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components to resolve the error. When I choose to export data to Excel and choose a file name of .xls, the export will error at 65,536 rows. If I choose to export data to Excel and select a file name of .xlsx, the export will complete without error. This is because in Excel 2010 there is a 1048576 row limit per sheet, and in Excel 97 there is a 65536 row limit per sheet.

I was able to google search 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components and found the driver.  Downloading the driver turned into a bit of a trick because it kept bombing out on me, but I was finally able to do so.  Once I ran the driver, I was able to export out more data.